# google Animation Chart with Drop Down list for Line Chart

Tags: javascript, animation, google-api, google-visualization, linechart

I am trying to `animate line chart` both with Switch `Button` and `Drop Down List`. I have a scenario where I have a `drop down List` with 4 different status (`Green, Red, Blue, Yellow`) and a `button` to switch between `Totals and Avg Time`. By looking at Google docs [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation) and able to Switch between `Totals` and `Avg Time`. The issue is with Drop down list, i want to filter my List by status whenever the user select status from drop down list and then draw a line chart. I don't want. to send request to server to just filter the list as already have all the values in list. Please let me know is there anyway I can achieve this. Thanks.

[image: Sample Line Chart]

## EDITED

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table for Avg Duration.
        var event_avg_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        event_avg_data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        
        <g:each in="${selectedProductList}" var="prdName">
        event_avg_data.addColumn('number', '${prdName}');
        </g:each>

        event_avg_data.addRows(${prdHDates?.size()});

        <g:each in="${prdHDates}" status="i" var="prdDateString">
        event_avg_data.setValue(${i}, 0, '${prdDateString}');
        <g:each in="${selectedProductList}" status="j" var="prdName">
        event_avg_data.setValue(${i},${j+1}, <%= aggregatedList.find {it.createDate == prdDateString && it.productName == prdName}? aggregatedList.find {it.createDate == prdDateString && it.productName == prdName}.avgProcessingTime:0 %>);
        </g:each>
        </g:each>

        // Create and populate the data table for Totals.
        var event_totals_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        event_totals_data.addColumn('string', 'Date');

        <g:each in="${selectedProductList}" var="prdName">
        event_totals_data.addColumn('number', '${prdName}');
        </g:each>

        event_totals_data.addRows(${prdHDates?.size()});

        <g:each in="${prdHDates}" status="i" var="prdDateString">
        event_totals_data.setValue(${i}, 0, '${prdDateString}');
        <g:each in="${selectedProductList}" status="j" var="prdName">
        event_totals_data.setValue(${i},${j+1}, <%= aggregatedList.find {it.createDate == prdDateString && it.productName == prdName}? aggregatedList.find {it.createDate == prdDateString && it.productName == prdName}.totals:0 %>);
        </g:each>
        </g:each>

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        var data = [];
        data[0] = event_avg_data;
        data[1] = event_totals_data;

        var options = {
            //chartArea:{left:0,top:15,width:"50%",height:"50%"},

            width:1200,
            height:500, fontSize:12,
            vAxis: {title: "# Of Events"},
            hAxis: {title: "Date"},
            pointSize:3,smoothLine:true,
            animation:{
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'out'
            },
        };
        var current = 0;
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('data-div'));
        var button = document.getElementById('switchChart');
        function drawChart() {
            // Disabling the button while the chart is drawing.
            button.disabled = true;
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
                    function() {
                        button.disabled = false;
                        button.value = 'Switch to ' + (current ? 'Avg Duration' : 'Totals');
                        button.innerHTML = 'Switch to ' + (current ? 'Avg Duration' : 'Totals');
                    });
            options['title'] = ' ${params.reportType} Aggregation chart by '+ (current ? 'Totals' : 'Avg Duration') +'  : [${params.reportFromDate}] to [${params.reportToDate}]';
            options['vAxis'] = {title: ''+ (current ? '# of Events' : 'Avg Duration (ms)')}
            chart.draw(data[current], options);
        }
        drawChart();

        button.onclick = function() {
            current = 1 - current;
            drawChart();
        }
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
```

Here is my HTML ... below the StatusList is having `[GREEN,RED,BLUE,YELLOW]` values

```
<div class="form-inline" name="switchForm">
<div class="form-group">
<button id="switchChart" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="" style="background-color: #48802C"></button>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Switch Status:</label>
        <g:select name="statusCode" id="statusCode"  class="form-control input-sm"
                  from="${statusList}"
                  value="${params.statusCode}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#using-controls--and-dashboards) with a [CategoryFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter)

Comment: CategoryFilter works if my Columns are Status but in my case my DataTable columns are product1, product2, product3....  not the Green, Red, Blue ... and the rows i am adding here are the Totals and Avg Time

Comment: CategoryFilter should work on any column -- you could use the results of the filter to get total and avg, similar to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37162679/5090771)

Comment: sorry, it looks very hard for to understand the logic in it, I have added my javascript code to show what I am doing for now, please look into it and let me know if I can use the CategoryFilter to my script. I am still trying to understand how to implement in my case. But thanks a lot for the information and your time