# Google charts, aggregate/group a filtered DataTable

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a DataTable, a DateRangeFilter and a aggregation object.
I was hoping I could use DateRangeFilter to filter the data in the DataTable and to limit the aggregation to the FILTERED DataTable. But that's not happening.
Am I doing something wrong (maybe forgot to refresh/draw), or something like that is not possible.

My code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0w5ehsc/

```
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('daterange_div'));
dashboard.bind(slider, tableChart);
dashboard.draw(dataAll);

var grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(
    dataAll,
    [0, 2],
    [
        {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can only bind one data table to a dashboard / filter.

in order to aggregate the filtered data table...

1. Wait for the `'ready'` event on the ChartWrapper
2. Aggregate the filtered data table from the ChartWrapper

see following example building off previous question...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['corechart', 'table', 'controls']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'dat_ym', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'user-id', label: 'User-Id', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'customer-id', label: 'Customer-Id', type: 'string'},
      {id: 's_minutes', label: 'minutes', type: 'number'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 1122} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 332} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 334} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 554} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 0} ]},
      {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 544} ]},
    ]
  });

  var options = {
    hAxis: {title: '', textStyle: { fontSize: '13' }, textPosition: 'in'},
    vAxis: {title: '', textStyle: { fontSize: '10' }},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 14}},
    isStacked: true
  };

  // build dashboard
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard-div'));
  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table-div',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });
  var dateSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'DateRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'slider-div',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });

  // Table 'ready' event
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    // group data by date, customer
    var grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(
      // get data table from ChartWrapper
      table.getDataTable(),
      [0, 2],
      [
        {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}
      ]
    );

    // sort grouped data
    grouped_data.sort([{column: 0},{column: 1}]);

    // get unique customers
    var custGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,
      [2]
    );

    // build customer data table
    var custData = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {id: 'dat_ym', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
      ]
    });

    // add column for each customer
    for (var i = 0; i < custGroup.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      custData.addColumn(
        {label: custGroup.getValue(i, 0), type: 'number'}
      );
    }

    // add row for each date / customer
    var rowDate;
    var rowIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < grouped_data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (rowDate !== grouped_data.getValue(i, 0).getTime()) {
        rowDate = grouped_data.getValue(i, 0).getTime();
        rowIndex = custData.addRow();
        custData.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate));
      }
      for (var x = 1; x < custData.getNumberOfColumns(); x++) {
        if (custData.getColumnLabel(x) === grouped_data.getValue(i, 1)) {
          custData.setValue(rowIndex, x, grouped_data.getValue(i, 2));
        }
      }
    }

    // draw agg table
    new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'agg-div',
      dataTable: custData,
      options: {
        allowHtml: true
      }
    }).draw();
  });

  // draw dashboard
  dashboard.bind(dateSlider, table);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-div">
  <div id="slider-div"></div>
  <div id="table-div"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id="agg-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: WhiteHat - slamdunk, again! Thanx a lot.
I have a new tiny question... on:

        rowIndex = custData.addRow();
        custData.setValue(rowIndex, 0, new Date(rowDate));

... is there a way to also set a label to the value set? I'm using the logic also to display customers by users, so now I have user-id in rows, and I'd like to have it show user-names. I could use join and/or views, but that would just add another layer of data. I'd like to fix it in the DataTable itself.
Thanx!

Comment: I've already tried that, I get an error: "custData.setLabel is not a function" ;(

Comment: sorry, it's `setColumnLabel` -- [here's](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setColumnLabel) the reference...

Comment: setColumnLabel is for the column, but I need to set label to the cell I've added with custData.addRow();

Comment: Not sure I follow, a cell can have a value and a formatted value, see setCell in previous link...?

Comment: setCell  works like a charm - thanx. I don't know how I missed that.